# How to describe the dry or solid state

Tags: word-choice

How to describe the dry, drying, or solid state for such as blood?

Do people just say `blood dries` or `the blood is dried`?

I did a web search of "`blood solidifies`", but it did not look like a correct usage.

I would like to understand both colloquial and formal usage of this description.

Another thing is that pudding does not dry out because when it solidifies, it ends in a gel-like, soft, and flexible state. How do I describe this solidifying and have-solidified state?

Comment: Blood coagulates (forms a gooey clot), then dries into something a little tarry-looking, then dries completely. It does not go through a flexible gel phase.

Answer (score 2):

*Dessicated*

[Merriam Webster](http://i.word.com/idictionary/desiccate) says

> des·ic·cate
>
> \ˈde-si-ˌkāt\ verb
> des·ic·cat·eddes·ic·cat·ing
> transitive verb
>
> 1
> :to dry up
>
> 2
> :to preserve (a food) by drying :dehydrate

Comment: Thank you very much, but I have a question. Can desiccate describe a pudding, which is not thoroughly dried?

Comment: @Superuser *Desiccate* is mostly used for making powder out of something fluent. E.g. milk or coconut, as M-W also states later: "add a cup of desiccated coconut to the mix". What you are looking for is my suggestion coagulate or another word fitting better the case of pudding: congelate

Comment: @AverageGatsby Perhaps you mean *fluid*?

Comment: @andy256 oh well, you got me. Thanks :). Nevertheless that doesn't change the fact that I am right.

Comment: @AverageGatsby I'm sure the OP will decide what word suits them best :-)

Comment: @Superuser - Something can be "partially dessicated" or "mostly dessicated".

Answer (score 1):

Congeal or coagulate are decent choices. Or you could always go the more "artistic" route and use a simile instead of one specific word, "The pool of blood by the victim's head had hardened to a state somewhere between old pudding and candle wax."

Answer (score 0):

coagulation / to coagulate [medicinenet](http://www.medicinenet.com/script/main/art.asp?articlekey=18597)

> The ***clotting*** of blood

[M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coagulate) says:

> coagulate (verb)
>   to become thick and partly solid